# Cannot refer to a non-final variable pcurl1 inside an inner class defined in a different method

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Doing an Application whcoh displays Markers on a Google Maps Fragment and opens a link in a browser on click, but i have a single marker where i dont want this to happen.

```
GoogleMap mMap;
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1)).getMap();
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(lat3, lng3))
    .snippet(bud1)
    .title(name1));
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(pcurl1);
        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
        startActivity(launchBrowser);
    }
});
```

Now i want to implement a `if (.... != "Your Position")` in the `onInfoWindowClick()` but I have no Idea how to check the Marker for this content inside the marker.

**Edit:** New Problem occured which is "Cannot refer to a non-final variable pcurl1 inside an inner class defined in a different method" and if I set it final it destroys it's funktion becasue it is set inside a loop.

Comment: try this 
LatLng position = marker.getPosition(); will return lng and lat for you and make your condition about it

Comment: @mohammedmomn could i even check for the color of the marker? becasue the Lat Lng are constantly changing and are not totally reliable.

Comment: you can save your marker in HashMap and check it if you want way to identify your markers on map

Answer (score 0):

`addMarker` method returns a `Marker` object. For your location marker, save if as a field e.g. `myLocationMarker` and in the callback do

```
if (!marker.equals(myLocationMarker)) {
    // ...
```